# Show the corresponding text of each attribute

Tags: jquery

need to show the text that is in the title attribute, made ​​an attempt however shows only the first text, I would like the text that appears each ID.

jQuery

```
var nombreItemText = $('#questionsForm .title').attr("title");
$("#questionsForm .title #question-count").text(nombreItemText);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TW4Ch/)

Comment: When you use attr() as a getter it'll only return the title of the first element. A solution is to loop through the $('#questionsForm .title') elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$('#questionsForm .title').each(function () {
    var nombreItemText = $(this).attr("title");
    $('span', $(this)).text(nombreItemText);
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TW4Ch/15/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each element and change the text for each context.

Currently you are getting the `title` attribute of the first element returned from the selection and setting the HTML for all `<span>`s to that value.

You can pass a function to the `text()` method and within that function the context is the current `<span>`, so you can target the parent `<h2>`s title attribute with `parent()` or `closest()`:

```
$(".container .title span").text(function(){
   return $(this).closest('h2').attr('title'); 
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TW4Ch/16/)

Answer (score 0):

When multiple elements are involved, you need to use `.each`:

```
// iterate over each .title element
$(".container .title").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // reference to .title element
    // find the nested span element
    $this.find('span')
        // and place the .title's title within
        .text($this.prop('title'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TW4Ch/2/

Also, you should be using `.prop`, but you'd have to know that [HTMLElement.title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.title) exists.